# Azure Logic Apps how to combine multiple JSON files to Blob storage

Tags: json, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps

I have a logic app that calls an API daily and saves the output to a .JSON file within a blob/storage container

These JSON files are then picked up by Power BI for reporting purposes.

The number of files is growing quickly and I want to see if it's possible to have just one JSON file which gets appended with the new data each day?

Power BI can then just connect to one file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **Update Blob** connector to append the data in a blob.

#### Follow the workflow:

[image: blobupdate]

**Blob Content - expression:**
Use this **concat** expression to add your API response to append in blob:

```
concat(body('Get_blob_content_(V2)'),outputs('Compose'))
```

**Result:**

[image: AppenedOutputBlob]